# polymer 2 paper-dialog auto open with iron-page inside

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I'm totally lost, there's any way to once a page is loaded shows a paper-dialog with an iron-page inside?

I just made it work by binding the dialog to a button, but not as a page_ready event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [documentation](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-dialog/elements/paper-dialog) of the paper-dialog you can find a open() method.
However, I was also able to open it with toggle(). Both seem to work fine.

```
this.$.dialogID.toggle();
this.$.dialogID.open();
```

In your scenario you want to open the dialog whenever the page is loaded.
So you could just add this function inside the ready().

```
ready() {
  super.ready();
  this.$.dialogID.toggle();
}
```

But it might be worth to mention that:

> Polymer no longer guarantees that the initial light DOM distribution is complete before ready is called. (Polymer documentation Lifecycle changes)

**THE CORRECT WAY**
So, I believe you could also just call it on attached. Of course this depends on your elements but it seems to be the easiest and straight forward answer I could come up with.

```
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    connectedCallback() {
        super.connectedCallback();
        this.$.dialogID.open();
    }
```